# saving data transferring through ajax preparation

Tags: javascript, ajax, dtls

I am passing data between ajax communications and it is basically a chat message. What I would like to know is how to prepare the data using `javascript` for transfer to the backend. They might post links and characters.

Something like urlEncode?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` would be the right method to prepare it for transfer via HTTP.

Comment: Thanks. Please post as answer so i can approve,.

Answer (score 0):

`encodeURIComponent` would be the right method to prepare it for transfer via HTTP.

For further description of the method, see f.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent